# pass javascript var into iframe

Tags: javascript, variables, iframe, youtube

I'd like to select a random youtube video from a list of 5 videos. I use javascript to assign the videos into an array then select one randomly. I then attempt to pass the variable of the random selected video in the iframe, however it's not loading the video.

3 questions: Am I passing the variable correctly? Is it even possible to pass a variable into an iframe that is accessing a different domain? If not, is there recommendations on how to achieve the desired outcome?

```
<script>
    var vtube=new Array()
    vtube[0]='UvJofkh8'
    vtube[1]='LdW3t801'
    vtube[2]='BWbcRkZ'
    vtube[3]='tgQhs81s'
    vtube[4]='ye5VpPCc'
    var whichvtube=Math.floor(Math.random()*(vtube.length))
    var vtubeselected=(vtube[whichvtube])
</script>


<iframe width="280" height="210" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/+vtubeselected?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Use HTML5 [PostMessage](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/web-messaging.html#crossDocumentMessages), [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=postmessage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var vtube = ['UvJofkh8', 'LdW3t801', 'BWbcRkZ', 'tgQhs81s', 'ye5VpPCc'];
var whichvtube = Math.floor(Math.random()*(vtube.length));
var vtubeselected = vtube[whichvtube];

document.write('<iframe width="280" height="210" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vtubeselected + '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
</script>
```

Comment: You are an artist! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

using jQuery: try this one. (`iframe` is the id of the iframe tag)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#iframe').src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/+vtubeselected?rel=0'+<whatever no want to add>
});
```